# Don't want to use global. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to use a variable which I defined within a function within a another but I don't want to use a Global.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import colorchooser
from tkinter import filedialog

x = "#000000"
#colour chooser
def mColour():
    color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=color).pack()
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Colour",message = "This feature has not been fully added yet.")
    x = color[1]
    print (color[1])
    return x
#printing message
def mhello():
    mtext = ment.get()
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=mtext, fg = (b)) # color varible = x
    mlabel2.pack()
#message
def mNew():
    messagebox.showerror(title = "(New) Error",message = "This feature has not been added yet.")
def mAbout():
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "About",message = "This Jono's susure personal data base. (Will be)")
#question message
def mQuit():
    mExit = messagebox.askokcancel(title = "Quit",message = "Are you sure")
    if mExit > 0:
        mGui.destroy()
#open
def mOpen():
    myopen = filedialog.askopenfile()
    mlabel3 = Label(mGui,text=myopen).pack()
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Open",message = "This feature has not been fully added yet.")


mGui = Tk()
ment = StringVar()

mGui.geometry("300x200+100+100")
mGui.title("Jono's Clock")

mlable = Label(mGui,text="My Label",fg = "red").pack()
mbutton = Button(mGui,text ="OK",command = mhello,fg = "red").pack()

mEntry = Entry(mGui,textvariable=ment).pack()



# Menu

menubar = Menu(mGui)

filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label = "New",command = mNew)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Open",command = mOpen)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Colour",command = mColour)
filemenu.add_command(label = "About",command = mAbout)
filemenu.add_command(label = "Quit",command = mQuit)


menubar.add_cascade(label = "File",menu = filemenu)
mGui.config(menu = menubar)



mGui.mainloop()
```

I'm using python 3.3 on windows 7.

I have add the rest of the code as requested.

Comment: You are not using `mColour` anywhere, but why not make `x` a *parameter* to the function? You already return it from the function.

Comment: Send it in as a parameter. `def mColour(x)`

Comment: Or consider to create own class with methods  `mhello` and `mColour`

Answer (score 3):

As the comments suggested, it would be good to pass the variable x as a *parameter* to the function.

```
def mColour(x):
    ...

def mHello(x):
    ...
```

Then when you want to call the functions:

```
x = "#000000" 

x = mColour(x)
mhello(x)
```

As a rule of thumb, defining global variables inside a function is a bad idea (with rare circumstances being exceptions). You want to keep local and global namespaces seperate. Functions allow the passing of arguments for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
#colour chooser
def mColour(x):
    color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    mlabel2 = Label(mGui,text=color).pack()
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Colour",message = "This feature has not been fully added yet.")
    x = color[1]
    print (color[1]) # Just a test
    return x

x = "#000000" # default text colour
mColour(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class instead as I don't think there's a way to access local variables from another function.

```
class Example(object):
    x="00006"

def c():
 print(Example.x)

c()
```

So here you're not using any globals at all

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Now your question makes a lot more sense. Because your functions are connected to these UI controls, it becomes much more difficult to pass parameters to them.

As such, you need a structure in which to store these values that you get from the UI. Then, when mhello() needs it, it has access to a function that can get the color from whatever structure you choose to use.

Now, mHello still can't take the color or the structure as a parameter, so you've got three options.

1) You can make something global, which you've already said you don't want to do.

2) You can make something static so that you can access the same instance from within mHello.

3) But I think the best answer is to use the structure that's commonly used: Make the UI a class. It has member variables to which the member functions have access. If mColor and mHello are members of the same class, then they can access whatever they need, pretty easily. Then you create some means of getting stuff outside the UI class so that it can be accessed, processed, and returned by whatever application you're writing.

(old answer:)

There are two ways.

EDIT: Both of which have already been suggested.

You could either make both of those functions members of the same class, and then `x` (which you should name something more descriptive) is accessible to both of them without being global.

Or...

You could (as suggested by other commentors) pass `x` as a parameter to your second function. mColor() even returns `x` which means you can store that value in another variable that you then pass to mhello().

Incidentally, I'm not sure why you're prefacing your methods with `m` but that typically identifies them as members of a class. Are they?

It would also be helpful to see the rest of the code, where you're actually **calling** these functions.

Comment: I still don't see where you're _calling_ `mhello()` and/or `mColor()`.

Comment: Near the bottom.
    
"filemenu.add_command(label = "Colour",command = mColour)"
 
"mbutton = Button(mGui,text ="OK",command = mhello,fg = "red").pack()"

Comment: Ah gotcha, they're tied to GUI controls, now your question makes a LOT more sense ;-)

That does make things a little more difficult.

I think the main problem you're running into is that you don't have a place to store these values. mColor() should be a "getter," that only gets the color from the GUI do that you can store it elsewhere.

Thus, you need a structure in which to store all the values that you want to keep track of.

Then mhello() will accept that value from whatever structure you choose to use as a parameter.

I'll update my answer.

Comment: I just realized that mHello() is still going to need access to the structure or the color or something, and it can't receive a parameter either. More in the answer...